# How can I guarantee that after a letter there is a number in shell

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I have this question on a project where I need to guarantee that after an "A" comes a number such as A21 or A2, but can't do the if statement properly... the middle one is the one that is giving problems, where I need to guarantee that there's a number after the "A"

```
if [[ $1 != [{A}]* ]] || [[ $1 == ^[A]*[0-9] ]] || [[ ${#1} -eq 1 ]]; then
echo "error"
fi
```

Comment: `if [[ $1 == A[0-9]* ]]; then ... else ... fi`

Comment: Please be specific about the kind of shell you are using. You are tagging the question as POSIX shell, which does not understang `[[`. You would use zsh (or ksh or bash) for this.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to check the input. Here is one way:

```
if [[ ! "$1" =~ ^A[[:digit:]]+$ ]]
then
    echo "Error"
fi
```

Comment: Quoting within `[[ .... ]]` isn't necessary.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin.  In this specific case that is true.  However, it is not true that quoting is never required within `[[...]]`.   Quoting is sometimes required on the RHS of `[[...]]`

Comment: Quoting `$1` isn't necessary, but it's not harmful, either. It's really not worth pointing out.

Comment: Except for those that think quoting the LHS in `[[ ... ]]` is required...